# Better way to export / batch insert from Elastic Map/Reduce (Amazon) to MongoDB hosted on EC2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, hive, elastic-map-reduce

So far I've looked at this Serde: 
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/tree/master/hive

What is the common practice for writing from Hive to Mongo? My last resort would be to write a Java program to read from Hive output format and batch write to MongoDB, but I'd imagine there's a better way.

Data size wise, I'm expecting to write 1-2 GB worth of data per run, and up to 10 runs per day.

Any link for resources would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with your 'last resort' solution?

Comment: It's one additional step in workflow, and making it distributed across  multiple machines may require quite a bit effort, also, I'm sure this has been done before, hopefully don't have to re-invent the wheel here.